# Snapping edge of one polygon to another using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, editing, snapping

How can I snap (move and snap) the edge of a polygon (corner) to the corner of another polygon uisng ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2?

Only the center of the polygon snaps to the edges/corners of the other polygon (see image).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented by @johns](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426332/snapping-edge-of-one-polygon-to-another-using-arcgis-pro#comment695677_426332):

> After selecting the polygon you want to move there will be a small x
> in the center.  (You might turn the imagery off to see it better.)
> Holding the Ctrl key use the edit tool to snap the x to the corner of
> the polygon you want to move.  Then using the cursor/edit tool to snap
> that x to the corner of the target polygon.
> https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/moving-a-feature-and-snapping-it-to-another-feature.htm

Answer (score 0):

After starting the Edit/Create Feature process, try right clicking the polygon you want to snap to, and select "Snap to Feature" (and select the type of snapping you want), then digitize the snapped verticies, then move out in to the area to be enclosed in your adjacent polygon, and continue digitizing......

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by holding Ctrl and moving the point, snapping it to the corner of the polygon, then I could snap the polygon from the corner to the corner of the polygon I wanted to move it to